# The ideal $(p)$ always factors in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime integer. Is there a relatively elementary way to see that $(p)$ is never prime in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

One can prove this by looking at the ramification and inertia groups, but I am curious if there is a simpler way.

Comment: If a prime remains prime in a Galois extension, the Galois group must be cyclic. Look at the Frobenius.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

One might hope that $(p)$ always factors in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ or $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, so that we could use the standard criteria for quadratic fields and quadratic residues to finish the problem. Recall that $(p)$ will split in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{2})$ whenever $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, and similarly for $3$.

Unfortunately, this is not true. Take $p=19$ for example. Here, neither $2$ nor $3$ is a residue.

However, when $2$ and $3$ are both non-residues, $6$ will be, because the product of two non-residues is a residue. So $(p)$ must split in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, or $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{6})$.